# Eclipse opening blank workspace

Tags: eclipse

I'm not even sure where to look for this issue. What happens, is that when I open Eclipse, it opens a blank workspace. Which, I then have to switch to my current one. This happens every time I open Eclipse now. Any idea where I should look to fix this?
(Eclipse Juno)

Comment: See if this is a solution to your problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17021193/2470353

Comment: Huzzah! This fixed it. I'm on Windows, and the config.ini file resides in the configuration folder under the Eclipse main dir.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse opens blank workspace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192607/eclipse-opens-blank-workspace)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the

- eclipse.ini in your eclipse installation directory
- shortcut you use to launch eclipse (if there is one).

If any of them contain a [-data somePath](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm) argument, then eclipse will always open that path as workspace.

Comment: I don't have that in either the shortcut I use, or the eclipse.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Go in Eclipse to **Window**->**Preferences**->**General**->**Startup and Shutdown**->**Workspaces** and activate the checkbox *"prompt for workspace on startup"* and restart your eclipse.

Now you can select on the eclipse start your favorite workspace and optional you can say "Use this as a default and do not ask again".

Comment: Hmmm. There definitely seems to be an issue with my Eclipse. I checked this box, and it doesn't ask me which workspace to open, it still just opens a blank workspace (mind you, I have two, both of which have projects in them).

Comment: Maybe you should try it with a reinstallation. Because the way what i should works normaly.

Comment: I'll probably do that at some point. It's not preventing me from working, it's just an irritation right now.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command **eclipse.exe -data C:\Development\Eclipse\Workspace**

FYI this happens due to install of some plugins.