# Eclipse opens blank workspace

Tags: eclipse, macos, workspace, eclipse-juno

I have this weird issue where the following happens:

- fresh eclipse juno install (with all updates applied)
- works fine for a while asking which workspace I want to open with a dialog on startup
- after a few days it stops prompting me for workspace, opens blank made up workspace instead in /Users/myself/Documents

If I check "preferences -> workspace -> startup and shutdown" everything seems fine, the only workspace in the list is the one I created and the checkbox that says "don't prompt for workspace" is **not checked**.

This happened a few times already on fresh eclipse installations and fresh hard drives (same machine but I replaced the hard drive, re-installed OS and everything for other reasons and now it happened again).

I am on:

- OSX 10.7.5
- Eclipse Juno (Service release 2)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: To whomever is voting to close to this question - please let me know where I am supposed to post it if not here. Getting an IDE to work properly is clearly programming related.

Comment: Did you try programmers' stackexchange?

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk no, because the question belongs here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem on OSX, for no reason, one fine day, Eclipse will start-up with a new blank workspace!

And to all the stupid answers and responders out there: YES I know how to set and select a default workspace! And NO creating a new workspace, re-importing lots of projects and loosing all my 30+ database connections under my Toad Extension, is not an option.

What I found is that

- For some reason Eclipse creates a directory `/Users/user_name/Documents/workspace` which is the blank workspace it starts-up with (incorrectly)
- My usual workspace is under `/Users/user_name/Documents/Development/eclipse`

The solution is (this is on Mac OSX, don't know if it is the same on Windows):

1. Goto your Eclipse directory where you run Eclipse from (mine is `/Applications/eclipse`)
2. In `{eclipse_dir}/configuration` open the file `config.ini`
3. Find the line `osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/...` and confirm that it is pointing to the bogus workspace directory.
4. Modify the path of this entry to point to the correct workspace
5. Save the `config.ini` file.
6. Try starting Eclipse and it should open your workspace now.
7. If your Eclipse get stuck loading plugins now, goto your workspace directory and look for the `.metadata` directory (its hidden). Inside the `.metadata` directory, remove the `.mylyn` directory and restart Eclipse.
8. Once Eclipse started with the correct workspace loaded, do a proper Eclipse shutdown to ensure your workspace is closed and saved properly.

This worked for Eclipse Juno.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! Will give it a shot, and let you know if it does the trick for me too :)

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is for Eclipse Juno

Comment: Still broken in Mars.2, and your solution still works.

Answer (score 2):

Just running this command helped me 
**eclipse.exe -data C:\Development\Eclipse\Workspace**

FYI this happens due to install of some plugins.

Answer (score 1):

This same problem happened to me on Windows on two separate Eclipse installations, without installing any plugin.

I was able to get my working Workspace by clicking on *File > Switch Workspace*, but closing and opening Eclipse again would reset it to a default Workspace.

What apparently solved this was to force Eclipse to save Workspace settings by ticking the *Prompt for workspace on startup* setting in *General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces*, which I had turned off.

The next time Eclipse opened, it asked me for the Workspace, and it had my correct one first in the list. I asked not to be prompted again for it and now it opens the right workspace when I launch Eclipse once again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as per [JJ-za's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17021193/2294676), except steps 2 and 3:

> 2. In {eclipse_dir}/**configuration/.settings** open the file **org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs** (when Eclipse is not running)
> 3. Find the line **`RECENT_WORKSPACES=`** and confirm that the workspace is pointing to the correct workspace directory **and that multiple workspaces are separated by `\n`**