# Eclipse shows empty files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a complex Maven project in eclipse, with a parent pom.xml file and a few childs. When I import as an Existing Maven project in Eclipse, I cannot open any of the files - the workspace shows an empty page. I have gone through this solution here - [Eclipse opens blank workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192607/eclipse-opens-blank-workspace) After restarting, I am able to view 1 or 2 files but in a min my workspace starts showing empty pages again.

Any workaround? 
In eclipse's configuration/congif.ini osgi.instance.area.default= points to my current workspace, and Maven's settings and repo are set to .m2 folder.

Eclipse gives me no errors.

I have tried deleting an entire .metadata folder and re-creating a project but a workspace for my project is still empty. For no-complex project pages are shown correctly.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse was used to create the project originally? Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Did you an update project on Maven?

Comment: The project was not created using eclipse at all. I am using Eclipse Neon. I believe that originally it could be recreated in Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can try to create a new workspace and import the parent project into it.

Comment: It did not help. What have helped, since a few times I had a NullPointerException, I followed this thread https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386648 and removed .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi because Error Log in Eclipse was complaining about this plugin. After restarting, I was able to view files in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I could have this fixed simply by trying to select/expand the folders above it. For e.g. Double click on 'src' and then click on the the folders 'main' and 'test' below it. Then click 'target' and finally click on 'pom.xml'. It works like wonders and strangely the content of pom.xml started to shown up in the workspace!!