# Eclipse is blank

Tags: java, eclipse

My issue is somewhat similar to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089241/5499914) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16192607/5499914), but it is not the same — I am in the correct workspace.

- HP ProBook 4535s
- Windows 7 Professional
- Eclipse Oxygen, installed ~3 weeks ago
- jre1.8.0_74

The problem I am having is that upon launch of Eclipse, there is nothing shown. During the launch, I am prompted for the workspace I wish to open; this is exactly how it has been in the past. I am working in a removable drive.

The title bar shows that I am looking at the project I worked on last. This is normal. However, I see nothing at all:

[image: This is what I see :(]

I have tried importing the files. No success. Window > Show View > [everything]. No success. Navigating to each project in cmd and `git pull`ing. No success. Creating a new project. No success (though the project did show up in Windows Explorer). Cleaning everything. No success. Switching workspaces. No success.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Reset your Java perspective. Try switching your workspace.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How do I reset my Java perspective? I'm new to Eclipse and Java (3 weeks)—layman's explanation!

Comment: Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective ... > Yes